# Can I modify a custom configuration section using ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `App.config` of the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Custom.Config" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </configSections>

    <kCura.Config configSource="Custom.config" />
</configuration>
```

With a custom configuration file `Custom.config` of the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Custom.Config>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</Custom.Config>
```

I've inherited this code, and there is no existing `ConfigurationSection` or `ConfigurationSectionHandler` associated with this `Custom.Config` section.

I can access the value of `foo` just fine with

```
 DirectCast(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Custom.Config"), System.Collections.IDictionary)
```

But now I would like to *update* this value, programatically (for testing purposes). **Is this possible?**

I've read the following, and I'm still stumped; they seem to imply that this namespace is only for reading values, not full CRUD:

- [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)
- [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using IConfigurationSectionHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228056.aspx)

Comment: There is no way to update and save the value in the source.  Depending on exactly how your deployment is set up, those values can be overwritten at that stage.  Tools like Octopus do this using transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to modify the `Custom.config` file on disk by using [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) then you'll need to call `RefreshSection` on the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will then refresh the named section so the next time that it is retrieved it will be re-read from disk.

Comment: Shocked this is not baked-in functionality within the System.Configuration namespace, but this is what I've resolved myself to for the time being.

Comment: I've hand rolled the same before when writing functional/acceptance tests.